Are sets of symbols, the {$t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_n$}, specified as in problem 4.137 of Lipschutz and Lipson¹, collections of linearly independent elements?
The question to be asked here, appears relevant to material that appears in at least two places in Lipschutz and Lipson$^1$. These places are
1, Pg 161, problem 4.137.
2, Pg 397, the proof of Theorem A.2 ( Existence of Tensor Product ).
Problem 4.137 is quoted below ( a slightly corrected version of )

Let $t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_n$ be symbols, and let $K$ be any field.
Let $V$ be the following set of expressions where $a_i \in K$:
\begin{equation*}
     a_1t_1+ a_2t_2+\cdots+a_nt_n \end{equation*}
Define addition in $V$ and scalar multiplication on $V$ by
\begin{align*}    ( a_1t_1+ \cdots+a_nt_n ) + ( b_1t_1+ \cdots+b_nt_n
 ) &=  ( a_1 +b_1)t_1+ \cdots+(a_n+b_n)t_n    \\ k( a_1t_1+
 a_2t_2+\cdots+a_nt_n  )&=ka_1t_1+ka_2t_2+\cdots+ka_nt_n \end{align*}
Show that $V$ is a vector space over $K$ with the above operations.
Also, show that ${t_1,\cdots,t_n}$ is a basis of $V$,
where
\begin{equation*} t_j=0t_1+\cdots+0t_{j-1}+1t_j+ 0t_{j+1}+\cdots+0t_n
 \end{equation*}

Writing out some of the $t_j$ definitions, we have
\begin{align*}
 t_1&=1t_1+0t_2+\dotsb+0t_n  \tag{1}\label{4958505_1}  \\
  t_2&=0t_1+1t_2+\dotsb+0t_n  \tag{2}\label{4958505_2}    \\
  &\vdots \\
 t_n&=0t_1+0t_2+\dotsb+1t_n.  \tag{3}\label{4958505_3}
\end{align*}
I am unsure about how to infer from equations like \eqref{4958505_1}–\eqref{4958505_3}.
Are the following, \eqref{4958505_star}, \eqref{4958505_starstar}, consistent with \eqref{4958505_1}–\eqref{4958505_3} or, are they somehow not allowed?
\begin{align*}
t_2&=0t_1+ct_1+\dotsb+0t_n \tag{*}\label{4958505_star}  \\
t_k&=0t_1+0t_2+\dotsb+0t_{k-1}\\
&\hphantom=+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}c_it_i+0t_{k+1}+\cdots+0t_n~~~~~,k=3,\dotsc,n.\tag{**}\label{4958505_starstar}
\end{align*}
\eqref{4958505_star} would say that $t_2$ is a multiple of $t_1$. Hence the vectors $\{t_1,t_2\}$ are linearly dependent, hence the vectors $\{t_1,t_2,\dotsc,t_n\}$ are linearly dependent.
\eqref{4958505_starstar} would say that $t_k$ is a linear combination of $\{t_1,t_2,\dotsc,t_{k-1}\}$. Hence again, the vectors $\{t_1,t_2,\dotsc,t_n\}$ are linearly dependent.
The $t_j$ here, are called symbols.
My question is: Are sets of symbols, the {$t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_n$}, specified as in problem 4.137 of Lipschutz and Lipson¹, collections of linearly independent elements?
Other Information
Another set of symbols is used in the proof of Theorem A.2 pg 397, this is the set of symbols $\{t_{ij}\}$, mentioned there.
NB the proof on pg 397 appears to contain errors.
Related Question
What do these equations, (1)-(3) , associated with problem 4.137 of Lipschutz and Lipson$^1$ actually mean?
Reference.
1, Seymour Lipschutz, PhD, Marc Lipson, PhD, SCHAUM’s outlines, Linear Algebra, Fourth Edition, McGraw Hill (2009).

I think the answers suggest that there is something wrong with asking this question, but, from my point of view, you are thinking like a mathematician.  If I say "here is a set with some symbols", you have every right to, and should, ask if symbols that look different are actually different.  The simple answer is that, as you suspect, the definition should specify that these symbols are linearly independent (although technically one can't define elements to be linearly independent, and instead must prove that such a vector space exists), but it is common to avoid doing so.

Your \eqref{4958505_star} and \eqref{4958505_starstar} are inferring additional structure on the set $t_1, t_2, \dotsc, t_n$. As written, the $t_k$ are just arbitrary symbols, and $V$ is the only structure that is being created.
$\newcommand\square{{\blacksquare}}\newcommand\triangle{{\bigtriangleup}}$For example, suppose our field is $\mathbb{F}_3$ and our set of symbols is $\{\square, \triangle\}$. Then our vector space contains the vectors
$$\begin{array}{ccc} 0 \square + 0 \triangle & 0 \square + 1 \triangle & 0 \square + 2 \triangle \\
1 \square + 0 \triangle & 1 \square + 1 \triangle & 1 \square + 2 \triangle \\
2 \square + 0 \triangle & 2 \square + 1 \triangle & 2 \square + 2 \triangle \end{array}$$
with the operations $(a \square + b \triangle) + (c \square + d \triangle) = (a + c) \square + (b + d) \triangle$ and $c(a \square + b \triangle) = (ac) \square + (bc) \triangle$ for any $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{F}_3$.
We can show that $1 \square + 0 \triangle$ and $0 \square + 1 \triangle$ form a basis for this vector space, and we can write $\square = 1 \square + 0 \triangle$ and $\triangle = 0 \square + 1 \triangle$, noting that we are still treating these as vectors within the vector space.
Very importantly, there is no relationship between the two symbols. So an expression like $\triangle = c \square$ has no truthful value within this vector space.
As a possibly more familiar (but also slightly confusing) example, if we take the field $\mathbb{R}$ and apply this approach to the set of symbols $\{1, i\}$ with the simplification that we write $c \cdot 1 = c$, then the vector space we create looks just like the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, but where we've only defined addition and multiplication by real numbers (so nothing that uses $i^2 = -1$).

Nice one. Your answer contains a useful explanation.

I think that \bigtriangleup might have \mathop spacing, so something like $0\blacksquare + 1\bigtriangleup$ 0\blacksquare + 1\bigtriangleup spaces funnily.  A cheap way to fix this is to surround them with braces: $0{\blacksquare} + 1{\bigtriangleup}$ 0{\blacksquare} + 1{\bigtriangleup}.  I edited accordingly.  (It's not actually necessary for \blacksquare, but I went ahead and did it for uniformity.)

This is immediate by noting that we can equivalently associate a vector $a \in K^n$ by the identification
$$
a = (a_1, \dots, a_n) \in K^n\quad \longleftrightarrow \quad a_1 t_1 + \cdots + a_n t_n \in V
$$
Your operations are now just the usual vector operations on $K^n$ and evidently the vectors $e_i$ (having all $0$ except $1$ in the $i$th slot) is the canonical basis of $K^n$.
I believe the main point of this exercise is to notice that the symbols $\{t_i\}_{i=1}^n$ do not matter at all, it is simply a way of organizing the entries of vectors in $K^n$.

Do ($*$) or ($**$) in the question, have any meaning?

Some of the understanding, that allowed me to put together this answer was gained from ConMan’s answer, see at
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4958625/553318
and also Other Information
Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$.
Lipschutz and Lipson$^1$, pg 121, gives the definition of ‘Linear Independence’ quoted below.

DEFINITION: We say that the vectors, $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_m$ in $V$ are $linearly~ dependent$ if there exist scalars $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_m$
in $K$, not all of them 0, such that
\begin{equation*}  a_1v_1+ a_2v_2+\cdots+a_nv_m =0 \end{equation*}
Otherwise, we say that the vectors are $linearly ~independent$.

Note in the above, the $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_m$ are all vectors from the vector space $V$.
Our vector space, $V$, consists of all expressions of the form
\begin{equation*}
     a_1t_1+ a_2t_2+\cdots+a_nt_n \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*} 
t_j=0t_1+\cdots+0t_{j-1}+1t_j+ 0t_{j+1}+\cdots+0t_n \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
The expressions ‘$t_j$’ may be considered as vectors in our space if we think of them as above, or as represented by the right hand sides of $(\mathbf{3.1}) ,\cdots,(\mathbf{3.n}) $, which are given below
Writing out some of the $t_j$ definitions, we have
\begin{align*}
 t_1&=1t_1+0t_2+\cdots+0t_n  \tag{3.1}  \\
  t_2&=0t_1+1t_2+\cdots+0t_n  \tag{3.2}   \\
  &\vdots \\
 t_n&=0t_1+0t_2+\cdots+1t_n.  \tag{3.n}
\end{align*}
Note that our zero vector in $V$ is the expression
\begin{equation*}
     0t_1+ 0t_2+\cdots+0t_n \tag{4}
\end{equation*}
The expression $a_1t_1+ a_2t_2+\cdots+a_nt_n $ can be thought of as a sum of expressions from $V$ if we use the right hand sides of $(\mathbf{3.1}) ,\cdots,(\mathbf{3.n}) $ to represent the simple one term expressions, the ‘$t_j$’.
Doing this
\begin{align*}
a_1t_1+ a_2t_2+\cdots+a_nt_n &= a_1(1t_1+0t_2+\cdots+0t_n) \\
&+ a_2(0t_1+1t_2+\cdots+0t_n) \\
  &\vdots \\
&+ a_n(0t_1+0t_2+\cdots+1t_n) 
\end{align*}
and this is equivalent to the expression ($\mathbf{4}$), if we take $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n=0$.
So, we have a sum of vectors from our space, that is equal to the zero vector of our space.
We are satisfying the equation
\begin{equation*}
     a_1t_1+ a_2t_2+\cdots+a_nt_n=0 \tag{5}
\end{equation*}
with the $t_j$ from our space, and all the $a_j$'s equal to zero.
The above way, all the $a_j$ being zero, is the only way that we can satisfy ($\mathbf{5}$), because we have no relations between the ‘$t_j$’, see Other Information. We cannot re-express any of the ‘$t_j$’in terms of the others, so we cannot find another set of coefficients to satisfy ($\mathbf{5}$).
Consider the case where at least one of the ‘$a_j$’ isn’t zero. This would imply a relation between the symbols, the ‘$t_j$’, but there is no such relation. See Conman’s answer, the first sentence is important here,  as is his comment given in Other Information.
Hence, by our definition of linear independence, from Lipschutz and Lipson$^1$,given previously, the expressions/vectors $t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_n$ are linearly independent.
Sets of symbols, the {$t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_n$} for some $n$, specified as in problem 4.137 of Lipschutz and Lipson$^1$, are collections of linearly independent elements.
Other Information
ConMan say’s, in the context of his example, within which he considers two symbols

Very importantly, there is no relationship between the two symbols. So
an expression like $\bigtriangleup = c \blacksquare$ has no truthful
value within this vector space.

Reference.
1, Seymour Lipschutz, PhD, Marc Lipson, PhD, SCHAUM’s outlines, Linear Algebra, Fourth Edition, McGraw Hill (2009).
